# Rapport Trusteer for Mac: how does it work?

Tags: plugins

Bank of America recommended me of installing something called Rapport from Trusteer.com, see [their website](http://www.trusteer.com/support/faq). Of course I don't trust these random security software. Especially if it seems to install a plug-in into the OS/browser which purportedly protect us!

I wonder if there's any info available how it works. Does it inject code into Safari/Firefox/Chrome? If so, how? Does it do via supported means (Safari/Firefox/Chrome extensions), or does it use mach_inject, say?

Comment: Well, Rapport has both Windows and Mac version, and I'm specifically asking how the Mac version works. I presume the mechanism the software uses to intervene the normal browser operations vary according to the OS, that's why I asked this question here... but yes, SuperUser might be more fitting. Is there a way to transfer a question across stackexchange sites?

Comment: @Yuji just wait for one of the mods, they'll decide if it should be migrated to SuperUser or not.

Comment: I wouldn't trust an app like this for many reasons. Blocking all these actions means that they would gain access to all of them + you don't know how much buggie it is. If I had to install it, it would be the first thing to suspect/blame whenever I jump into an unexpected system behavior..

Comment: @nuc I completely agree with that. That's why I asked the question here. I love&hate haxies... it was a lot of fun to write InputManager plugins. But I don't want anybody else to abuse my system like that.

Answer (score 1):

Just working from the list of things it purports to accomplish on the web, I don't see how it could possible be just a browser plugin/addon/extension. Many of the things it claims could be done in browser, but a couple stand out to me:

1. screen capture prevention. I don't think they could do this from within the browser plugins. At least not via the APIs I've seen in firefox/chrome.
2. keylogger blocking. Their website claims they somehow block keyloggers from capturing your keystrokes. I find that claim more than a little dubious for any software.

So I'm going to bet it uses a fair bit more than just the supported means. But that's without downloading it and ripping it apart, something I'm just not up to tonight.